# Codeigniter - Show Number with Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, sum

I have `Payment Table`. This Payment Table has `paymentCusId(It is Customer Id)`, `paymentCredit` and `paymentDebit` rows etc... How can I show, If Customer's Balance is *less than 50 euros*, I want to show how many customers balance *less than 50 euros*.

> For example, 5 customers balance less than 50.

Can I solve this using **sql query** or **php conditions** ?

Code below:

```
$this->db->select('payment.paymentCusId, sum(paymentCredit) - sum(paymentDebit)');
$this->db->from('payment');
$this->db->where('sum(paymentCredit) - sum(paymentDebit) <', 50);

$query_debit =  $this->db->get();

$number = $query_debit->num_rows();

echo $number;
```

This code not working well. What can I do to show the number of **customers less than 50 euros?**

Comment: anyone reply this?

Comment: do you have a table field that keeps record of customer balance?

Comment: Question was resolved below already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you are trying to perform has two errors.

1 - In order to you functions that aggregate function you need to group the result using GROUP BY

2 - Aggregation functions on the WHERE clause do not work, you need to put it in the having clause.

For your case the correct query would be:

```
$this->db->select('payment.paymentCusId, sum(paymentCredit) - sum(paymentDebit)');
$this->db->from('payment');
$this->db->group_by('payment.paymentCusId');
$this->db->having('sum(paymentCredit) - sum(paymentDebit) <', 50);

$query_debit = $this->db->get();

$number = $query_debit->num_rows();

echo $number;
```

For more information about codeigniter query builder check their [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

A good way to figure out if your query is correct before trying to get results or num_rows, etc, is to verify it has an error:

```
    $error = $this->db->error();
    if($error) {
       echo $error['message'];
       echo $error['code'];
    }
```